# URL parameter values are missing in action method of ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wanted to pass textarea value and some other parameters to action method. so i did using the jquery in the following way.

**View:-**

```
@Html.TextArea("aboutme")
<a id="@Profile.Id" title="@Profile.name" onclick="SubmitProfile(this)" >
 Submit</a>
```

**Jquery Method:-**

```
function SubmitReview(e,count) {    
    var Text = "'"+jQuery("#aboutme").val()+"'";
    var url = 'http://' + window.location.host + '/Controller/ActionMethod?' + 'id=' + e.id       + '&name=' + e.title + '&aboutme=' + Text;
    jQuery("#Profile").load(url);

}
```

**Action Method:-**

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod(string id,string name,string aboutme)
        {
            //
        }
```

Above code is working fine, but when ever any one of the parameter value contains  **spaces** in it. In Jquery method URL looks fine.but in action method it trims the value upto 1st space and remaining parameters are null.

Let me explain with some example

let say id='123',name='amith cho' ,aboutme='i am software engg'

Url in Jquery method

```
url='http://localhost/Controller/ActionMethod?id=123&name=amith cho ,aboutme=i am software engg'
```

but it is getting in action method as `id=123` `name=amith` `aboutme=null`

How to solve this?

Comment: sending data to action using this url `http://localhost/Controller/ActionMethod?id=123&name=amith cho ,aboutme=i am software engg` is a **bad**, *bad*, `bad` practice... POST these values instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should url encode the value of the input if you are passing it as a query parameter.

```
function SubmitReview(e,count) {
    var Text = jQuery("#aboutme").val(); // quotes aren't necessary
    var url = 'http://' + window.location.host + '/Controller/ActionMethod?' 
                   + 'id=' + e.id 
                   + '&name=' + encodeURIComponent(e.title) 
                   + '&aboutme=' + encodeURIComponent(Text); 
    jQuery("#Profile").load(url);

}
```

If your string contains extra characters not handled by encodeURIComponent, you can try this function, referenced from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).  Replace the calls to encodeURIComponent above with calls to this.

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, "%2A");
}
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent() not allowing these special characters ~!*()' 
so it is breaking...

Comment: @User_MVC - updated with alternative suggestion from the docs to include more escaped characters.